# ory/dockertest not working on GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, github-actions, clickhouse, ory

I can locally create and use a docker container with ory/dockertest.

However when trying to run dockertest with tests on GitHub actions, the docker container automatically gets exited before any tests can be run with the container. (see output of `docker ps -a` below when sshed into the test server on GitHub)

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                        PORTS                                         NAMES
32b6ec43b96a   clickhouse/clickhouse-server:latest   "/entrypoint.sh"         13 minutes ago   Exited (232) 13 minutes ago                                                 sweet_hertz
4e750bc3dcf1   clickhouse/clickhouse-server:latest   "/entrypoint.sh"         17 minutes ago   Exited (232) 17 minutes ago                                                 naughty_buck
```

this behavior is very confusing to me. Is there something im missing here?

EDIT

Investigated container logs, this is what was returned, looking for solutions now...

```
/entrypoint.sh: create new user 'clickhouse_test' instead 'default'
Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 0, Not found: https_port (version 22.9.1.2603 (official build))
```

EDIT:

Fixed by using yandex/clickhouse instead of clickhouse/clickhouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using yandex/clickhouse instead of clickhouse/clickhouse

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).